# Logical shenanigan or not: replacing unbounded quantifiers with bounded one

Tags: logic, proof-verification

This can't possibly be right, is it? This is 1 basic line of an argument I found in a paper, which is replicated in many other sources, and the same kind of argument is used in other papers, so I am hoping it is right, but I can't see how the claim can be true.

Here $M$ is a model of first-order Peano arithmetic. $I$ is an initial segment which is also a substructure. $c_{i}$ is an increasing sequence in $I$ (it is in fact a set of diagonal indiscernbles of $M$, but I don't think that is relevant), $a\in I,a<c_{i_{0}}$ for some $c_{i}$ and $\phi(a,\overline{v})$ is a formula with only bounded quantifier.

The paper claimed that:

"

$I\vDash \exists v_{1}\forall v_{2}\exists\ldots\exists v_{n}\phi(a,\overline{v})$

if and only if $\exists i_{1}>i_{0}\forall i_{2}>i_{1}\exists\ldots\exists i_{n}>i_{n-1}$ such that $I\vDash \exists v_{1}<c_{i_{1}}\forall v_{2}<c_{i_{2}}\exists\ldots\exists v_{n}<c_{i_{n}}\phi(a,\overline{v})$

"

I can't see how this could possibly be true. The $\Rightarrow$ direction seems to fail when you deal with the pair $\forall\exists$, and the $\Leftarrow$ direction seems to fail when you deal with the pair $\exists\forall$.

Help! I had been wrecking my brain over this for a few days.

(note that we might be dealing with non-standard model, so you can't assume that there will be a finite number of number less than a number)

Comment: You write "$I$ is an initial fragment". Do you mean "$I$ is an initial segment"?

Comment: @AlexKruckman:Yes, indeed.